# SignalR context within core3.1 controller - no context.clients

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr

I am trying to call a SignalR Hub Action from a controller.

On my controller I have this:

```
    private readonly IHubContext<TurnHub> _hubContext;

    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IHubContext<TurnHub> hubContext)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _hubContext = hubContext;
        _gameService = new GameService(ModelState);
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Test()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> TestMessage()
    {
        await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("TurnChanged", 1);
        return View();
    }
```

When I break on hub context, I can see nodes for "Clients" and "Groups" but there are no clients or groups under that level. Running the controller action sees no errors, but the message isn't pushed to the client.

On the hub I have this:

```
public class TurnHub : Hub
{

    public async Task EndTurn(int nextUser)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("TurnChanged", nextUser);
    }
}
```

And the view has this:

```
<script>
    var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/TurnHub").build();
    connection.on("TurnChanged", function (nextUser) {
        debugger;
        alert(nextUser);
    });
</script>
```

I was expecting any browser window that was displaying that view to alert when one of the clients hits that controller action (Called from a button on that view).

What am I doing wrong?

I have the signalr core package installed, the js file from "add client library" @microsoft/signalr. There are no console errors on the browser to say anything is wrong!

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your javascript client you need to start the hub connection. Like this

```
connection.start();
```

The start will return a promise so you could do some stuff after the hub has been connected. Also failures in connection can be tracked by catching errors on that promise.

Comment: That's why you ask a second set of eye's to look at things. But you are welcome